# Using Swagger generated Angular API client library to post data with Angular 11

Tags: angular, rest, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to use Swagger generated Angular API client library from https://editor.swagger.io/ in Angular 11. I can call the API library to get results. However, I couldn't figure out how to post data from a form to the library. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

JSON data from the form looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "requestDetail": "Gift for Lucy's birthday",
  "requestItem": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "requestId": 1,
      "item": "Giant Poo Bear",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "requestId": 1,
      "item": "Giant Panda",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

request-create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import {RequestCreateDto}  from '../../api/models/request-create-dto';
import {GoodsRequestService} from '../../api/services/goods-request.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './request-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./request-create.component.scss']
})


export class RequestCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  requests: RequestCreateDto[]=[] ;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private requestService: GoodsRequestService) { }
  
  RequestForm = this.fb.group({
    requestTitle: ['', Validators.required],
    requestItem: this.fb.array([
      this.newItem()
    ])
  });

  newItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      item: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['1',Validators.required],
    })
  }

  removeItem(i:number) {
    this.requestDetails.removeAt(i);
  }
   
  get requestDetails() {
    return this.RequestForm.get('requestItem') as FormArray;
  }
  addRequestDetails() {
    this.requestDetails.push(this.newItem());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRequests();
  }
  getRequests(): void {
    this.requestService.apiGoodsRequestGet$Json().subscribe(requests => (this.requests = requests));
  }
}
```

goods-request.service.ts method (API)

```
/**
   * This method provides access to the full `HttpResponse`, allowing access to response headers.
   * To access only the response body, use `apiGoodsRequestPost$Json()` instead.
   *
   * This method sends `application/*+json` and handles request body of type `application/*+json`.
   */
  apiGoodsRequestPost$Json$Response(params?: {
    body?: RequestCreateDto
  }): Observable<StrictHttpResponse<RequestReadDto>> {

    const rb = new RequestBuilder(this.rootUrl, GoodsRequestService.ApiGoodsRequestPostPath, 'post');
    if (params) {
      rb.body(params.body, 'application/*+json');
    }

    return this.http.request(rb.build({
      responseType: 'json',
      accept: 'text/json'
    })).pipe(
      filter((r: any) => r instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((r: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        return r as StrictHttpResponse<RequestReadDto>;
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be pretty straightforward.

```
....

post(){
this.requestService.apiGoodsRequestPost$Json({body: this.requestForm.value}).subscribe(
  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
)

...
```